# C++ pointer vs object

Tags: c++

Could you please clear up a question for me regarding pointer vs object in C++. I have the below code that has a class called "person" and a list that allows for 100 objects of that class type.

```
class person {...}

int main {
    person* mylist;
    mylist = new person[100];
    mylist[0].set_name("John")
    // ...
}
```

In this code I can call a method of the class by `mylist[0].set_name()` meaning (by my understanding) that `mylist[0]` is an object (hence the `.` operator to call a method). The code works fine.

I have another project where the "person" class is used as a base class to derive classes "carpenter" and "welder". The derived classes simply overwrite a virtual function called salary in the base "person" class to allow for a different calculation of salary.

```
person* mylist[100];
mylist[0] = new carpenter;
mylist[0]->set_name("John");
```

This code works fine as well. My question is - why in the first code I can call the `set_name` method using the `.` (meaning `mylist[0]` is an object) and in the second code I have to use the `->` operator (meaning `mylist[0]` is a pointer to the object)?

Comment: In the first case you have an array of objects, in the second - an array of pointers to objects.

Comment: A *pointer* (raw, smart, or contrived) **is** an *object*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`T*` represents a *pointer type*, which represents a variable that contains a *"reference"* (usually a memory address) to some instance of type `T`. Using a real world comparison, a `T*` pointer stands to `T` like a street address stands to a building.

Pointers allow you to refer to some instance owned by some other variable, and you can use a *valid, non null* instance of `T*` to read and write on a `T`. In this, they are similar to another C++ concept, references (written as `T&`), which allow you to *alias* variables, but differ significantly from pointers by not being *objects* in their own regard.

A pointer is, in fact, an object itself, with each pointer variable having its own unique address and being thus storable and referenceable. For instance, you can have pointers to pointers (`T**`) and references to pointers (`T*&`), but not pointers to references - pointers *exist*, while references may not (they are usually implemented as pointers underneath though).

To reflect the this "indirect" nature of pointers, C and C++ provide you with two different operators which allow you to *dereference* a pointer (`*` and `->`), and to *reference* a variable (`&`).

For instance, you may do the following:

```
struct A { int x; };

// ... 

A a {};
A *aptr { &a }; // `&` takes the address of `a` and stores it into the `aptr` variable of type `A*`

aptr->x = 33; // `->` is equivalent here to `(*aptr).x`, a.x is now 33

A a2 {};
A **aptrptr { &aptr }; // pointer to pointer

*aptrptr = &a2; // `aptr` now points to `a2`
```

`operator->` is basically syntactic sugar that avoids you some cumbersome expressions like `(*aptr).x`.

References, being basically just aliases to something else, do not need any special syntax at all, and are always converted transparently when neeeded:

```
int x { 33 };
int &xref { x }; // `xref` refers to `x`
xref = 12; // `x` is now 33

int y = xref; // copies `x` into `y`, no special syntax needed
```

Pointers are also used in the C language to access arrays, which always decay to a pointer as soon as they are referred to in expressions. This is messy and it's one of the reasons `std::vector` and `std::array` should always be used in their place when feasible.

```
int x[33];
x[3] = 44; // equivalent to `*(&x[0] + 3) = 44`
```

Finally, the "indirect" nature of pointers and references allow C++ to convert a `Derived*` to a `Base*`, given that a derived class *contains* a full instance of its base (it gets more complicated with multiple inheritance though).

Every class that inherits or contains from another class containing `virtual` methods will include a hidden pointer to a _Virtual Method Table`, a list of pointers to functions which will be used to dispatch the virtual methods to the correct implementation.

PS: in modern C++, you should rarely need raw pointers. The correct approach is to use containers such as `std::vector`, `std::array` and `std::string`, and special pointer-like wrappers called *smart pointers* (like `std::unique_ptr`) every time you need a pointer for some reason. These will handle the lifetime of a pointer for you, avoiding memory leaks and vastly simplifying memory handling. For the same reason, the `new` operator should be mostly considered as being deprecated and should not be used at all (unless in *placement new* expressions, are potentially dangerous if used improperly).

Comment: `x[3] = 44;` isn't equivalent to `*(&x[0] + 3) = 44;`
`x` is already an address, so it would actually be like this: `*(x + 3) = 44;`

Comment: @ШерифГрей `x` is not an address. `x` is a variable of type `int [33]` which _decays_ to an `int*` equivalent to `&x[0]` when used in an expression. You can bypass this behaviour by using references to arrays, for instance, if you have a function defined like `template <std::size_t N> void func(int (&arr)[N]);` and you call it like `func(x)`, there would be no pointer decay. See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array), under _"Array-to-pointer decay"_.

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive explanation. Am I to understand that in the first block of code of my question, mylist is declared as a pointer but then the 'new' command is setting this pointer as the start of an array of 100 objects? Is that why I can refer to mylist[0] as an object? Then, in the second block of code, mylist is declared as an array of 100 pointers and the 'new' command simply initialises an object at a given address pointed to by mylist[0]. Is that what happens?Thank you again for your time.

Comment: @madac yes, your understanding is correct. You are welcome, by the way :)

Answer (score 0):

basically the first case works like this: you have an array of objects. To access the object fields and methods you use `.` operator.
In the second case you have an array of pointers to an object. Pointer is just a memory address, that points to an object of some type. In your case, this is an array of pointers to class `person`. By default, these pointers are invalid; you have to set them to the address of some existing object. `new` creates an object on the heap, and returns you an address of that object. In order to access the value behind the pointer, you have to de-reference it. The syntax is this:

```
some_type obj;
some_type* ptr = &obj; // get the address of the object
(*ptr).some_method(); // de-reference the pointer and call it
ptr->some_method(); // same
```